# retrieve a phase from a noisy 1d periodic signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, phase

I have a periodic signal on a given grid, say :

```
t = 1:30;
omega = 2*pi/18.431;
phi = -pi+2*pi*rand(1);   % a random phase [-pi,pi]
x = sin(omega*t+phi);     % the signal
x = x+0.5*rand(1,length(x)); % add some noise
```

[image]

Now I want to retrieve the phase `phi`. There are a few approaches to that, for example, to fit this to a `sin`, but that takes way too long if I need to do it 1e6 times (unless there's a way to parallelize it?).  Another is to use `fft`. The problem is that my grid is not good enough to pick exactly that frequency, hence the phase associated with it (and I cant change that). How can I manage to get that phase by other means? (and how can I estimate the error in that phase retrieval? I expect traces too noisy to be well estimated and I'd like to know the phase error in that case)

Comment: Is this assuming you know the frequency in advance?

Comment: yes, I know the frequency in advance, but it is not commensurate with the grid, and undersampled in a sense...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FT is just a correlation of your signal with a cosine and sine wave, and the results give you phase and magnitude. Instead of doing a FT of the whole signal, just calculate the coefficient at your frequency of interest.

As for the accuracy - the longer your signal, the more 'distinct' your inspection frequency will be from adjacent frequencies, so I'm not sure you can get much more accuracy with this method without a longer sample length.

EDIT:

Haven't got Matlab to hand, so going to do this in Python (I've tried to make it look similar to Matlab):

```
from numpy import arange, pi, cos, dot, exp, angle
from numpy.random import rand

N = 1  # Number of cycles
t = arange(30 * N) + 1  # [1, 2 ... 30 * N]
omega = 2 * pi / 18.431
phi = -pi + 2 * pi * rand(1)[0]
x = cos(omega * t + phi)
x = x + 0.5 * rand(len(x))

coeff = dot(x, exp(-1j * omega * t))
phase = angle(coeff)

print "Actual phase:", phi
print "Calculated phase:", phase
```

This gives fairly good results even for a single cycle. Occasionally the calculated phase is `2*pi` out, which doesn't mean it's giving the wrong answer, but is something to bear in mind for subsequent calculations.

Increasing the number of cycles `N` produces consistently good results, but this will obviously increase the calculation time so you might want to play around with it and find a compromise for speed vs accuracy (depending on your application).

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: thanks for the edit, I guess I can learn how to calculate that Fourier coefficient, but am not sure that this is a viable technique (for 1e6 traces). Can you please show me how can I calculate that integral in matlab in an efficient manner? (also `angle` in matlab does just what the `phase` you wrote does)

Comment: Instead of `atan`, I'd use `atan2` so that you get the full zero to 2*pi phase angle.  So, you'd do: `phi = atan2(imag(coeff),real(coeff));`

Comment: I haven't used Matlab in a while, so probably best to treat the example as pseudo-code :-)

Comment: thanks for the edit, I've tried it but didn't get an agreement, shouldn't `fs=1/(dt*N)` with `dt=t(2)-t(1)` and N the # of points in the grid?, also `[0:length(t)]` should be `[1:length(t)]`? (because `x` has length of `t` and in matlab you start with `1` as the first index? (maybe its [0:length(t)-1] ?) can you please add an example that shows that this indeed is the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching local minimums/maximum to get both phase and frequency.

*EDIT*

If you know frequency you can normalise signal, multiply and integrate once with cos and then with sin. This get you directly A and B if signal is presented as

```
A*sin(x) +B*cos(x)
```